# CLion Cygwin (32 bit) version 2.11.2 GDB Debugging Error 0xc0000135

Tags: c++, mono, gdb, cygwin, clion

**EDIT 1**
This seems to be related to linking to the mono library, once I remove any kind of reference to mono code and remove the linking to the library from my CMakeList.txt file, debugging works as expected.

**EDIT 2**
Okay, I've discovered something interesting. This actually might not have anything to do with how I am linking libraries, it appears to be directly related to how I am initialising a class in my unit test. For whatever reason, if I use my normal syntax of **TypeDeclaration variableName;** the unit test fails immediately with the error code 0xc0000135, but if I change it to read **TypeDeclaration variableName();** the code will run. Only problem is that I then get a warning stating **empty parenthesis interpreted as a function declaration**. I came from linux using g++ to compile my code and there was never an issue, now all of a sudden trying to compile on windows using cygwin or mingw means I can't use the normal standard c++ syntax to actually do work...

**Edit 3**
I've discovered that this issue is occurring because the libraries I am dependent on aren't actually being copied into the build directory of my unit test project. If I manually copy the required libraries into my build directory debugging works as expected, will need to learn how to express this requirement in CMakeList.txt

**More Details**

CLion Specifics
CLion 2018.3.1
Build #CL-183.4588.63, built on December 5, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

**Toolchain Settings**

Cygwin 32 bit version 2.11.2
CMake version 3.13.1
Make version 4.2.1
gcc version 7.3.0
Debugger Cygwin GDB version 8.1.1

catch.hpp for unit testing.

**Problem**

When debugging a unit test, CLion reports the following error:

**During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.**

Google returns a lot of Qt and netbeans related results, everyone suggests to add C:\mingw\bin to the system PATH variable. However I am not using mingw I am using cygwin. I tried adding C:\cygwin\bin to my PATH directory but that does not help.
 I also tried switching toolchain to use mingw to see if that would help. but the same problem occurs with debugging.

Not sure what else I can do to proceed in resolving this one, any ideas would be most welcome.